# Azure self hosted agent offline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

It seems my Azure self hosted Linux agent has crashed:

```
/etc/systemd/system/vsts.agent.***.Dev\x20Tools.deploytools\x2d***.service
● vsts.agent.***.Dev\x20Tools.deploytools\x2d***.service - Azure Pipelines Agent (***.Dev Tools.deploytools-***)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vsts.agent.***.Dev\x20Tools.deploytools\x2d***.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-07-27 14:20:41 UTC; 5min ago
 Main PID: 26601 (runsvc.sh)
    Tasks: 8 (limit: 2322)
   Memory: 11.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/vsts.agent.***.Dev\x20Tools.deploytools\x2d***.service
           ├─26601 /bin/bash /home/peter/runsvc.sh
           └─26604 ./externals/node10/bin/node ./bin/AgentService.js

Jul 27 14:26:13 deploytools-*** runsvc.sh[26601]:    at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
Jul 27 14:26:13 deploytools-*** runsvc.sh[26601]:    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
Jul 27 14:26:13 deploytools-*** runsvc.sh[26601]:    at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
Jul 27 14:26:13 deploytools-*** runsvc.sh[26601]:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
Jul 27 14:26:13 deploytools-*** runsvc.sh[26601]:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.HostTraceListener.CreatePageLogWriter()
Jul 27 14:26:13 deploytools-*** runsvc.sh[26601]:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.HostTraceListener..ctor(String logFileDirectory, String logFilePrefix, Int32 pageSizeLimit, Int32 retentionDays)
Jul 27 14:26:13 deploytools-*** runsvc.sh[26601]:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.HostContext..ctor(String hostType, String logFile)
Jul 27 14:26:13 deploytools-*** runsvc.sh[26601]:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Program.Main(String[] args)
Jul 27 14:26:13 deploytools-*** runsvc.sh[26601]: Agent listener exited with error code null
Jul 27 14:26:13 deploytools-*** runsvc.sh[26601]: Agent listener exit with undefined return code, re-launch agent in 5 seconds.
```

But I can't find a proper error. Can anyone see what is going on?

Comment: Did you check available space?

Comment: Same Issue. Did you find any solution? I have upgraded my memory and space but still same error. It runs fine on ./run.sh command but not on ./svc.sh start.

Comment: @WaleedTariq sorry, yes in the end it was a disc space issue.

Comment: @WaleedTariq when that happens, it's because you've installed the service in a sudo session. You need to `./svc.sh stop`, `./svc.sh uninstall`, then login as a non root user and run `sudo ./svc.sh install` and `sudo ./svc.sh start`